# Accidentally deleted external USB Drive and now I can't access it

Tags: disk-utility, usb, disk-format, formatting, diskutil

I accidentally formatted an external USB Drive to APFS, I needed to change it back so I found this walkthrough:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-revert-back-to-apples-hfs-from-apfs/

and I ran this command:

```
diskutil apfs deleteContainer /dev/disk2s2
```

Now I can't use the USB drive anymore, I can't see it in diskutil via command line.

The only place I can find it is in system information as so:

```
STORE N GO:

  Product ID:   0x0302
  Vendor ID:    0x18a5
  Version:  11.00
  Serial Number:    1314110000000445
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Verbatim
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 18
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

But it doesn't seem to acknowledge that this is a drive, how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried Disk Utility.app?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes, it won't be found anywhere as a storage device.  Disk Utility.app, diskutil, I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: If you have access to a PC, maybe it can be formatted via Windows. Is this drive one of [these types of drives](http://www.verbatim.com/prod/hard-drives/portable/store-n-go-usb-3.0/) or something similar from Verbatim?

Comment: @IconDaemon Unfortunately no it's just a usb thumbdrive: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Verbatim-4GB-Store-n-Go-USB-Flash-Drive-Red/13073369

 it's now mounting (I noticed it mounts after 15 minutes): I get the following results in diskutil:

`
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *4.0 GB     disk2

`

However I'm not able to format it or anything.

Windows has similar issues, it sees the device as a USB device but it won't let it run as storage.

Comment: If there's no data on the drive you must retain, the device itself should be relatively inexpensive to replace. If it is brand new, perhaps Verbatim would replace it. I've had a number of thumb drives, cheapos and top-of-the-line models, fail without warning. Good luck!